# Next-Auth callbacks returns invalid token

Tags: javascript, session, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I have an Auth Provider using Twitter Provider, it's runs okay when i click login and redirect me to login page with login button hidden (because there is a session) and my console show that the session data and token are correct, but somehow it's run once again (the callback) and invalidate my previous session data

[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import TwitterProviders from 'next-auth/providers/twitter';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    TwitterProviders({
      clientId: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
      if (account){
        // Add access_token to the token right after signin, jwt callback runs twice but the second time account was undefined
        if ( account.provider && !token[account.provider] ) {
          token[account.provider] = {};
        }
        
        if ( account.oauth_token ) {
          token[account.provider].oauth_token = account.oauth_token;
        }
        
        if ( account.oauth_token_secret ) {
          token[account.provider].oauth_token_secret = account.oauth_token_secret;
        }
        
        token.account = account;
        console.log('=================================================================')
        console.log("Token :", token)
        return token;
      }
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      console.log("Session :", session)
      console.log('=================================================================')

      return session;
    }
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
})
```

First run:

```
=================================================================
Token : {
  name: '001 nlptest',
  email: undefined,
  picture: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1648862909584515073/S3KDvPUY.png',
  sub: '1648862842563727360',
  twitter: {
    oauth_token: '1648862842563727360-CKNjKyBuccSsNmGMxCrfUX46ueyXLB',
    oauth_token_secret: 'w15pRV9QujYSDFbrP9w4drw1daiebGYD9cBbaJuc2YI11'
  },
  account: {
    provider: 'twitter',
    type: 'oauth',
    providerAccountId: '1648862842563727360',
    oauth_token: '1648862842563727360-CKNjKyBuccSsNmGMxCrfUX46ueyXLB',
    oauth_token_secret: 'w15pRV9QujYSDFbrP9w4drw1daiebGYD9cBbaJuc2YI11'
  }
}
Session : {
  user: {
    name: '001 nlptest',
    email: undefined,
    image: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1648862909584515073/S3KDvPUY.png'
  },
  expires: '2023-05-21T04:11:31.703Z'
}
=================================================================
Session : {
  user: {
    name: '001 nlptest',
    email: undefined,
    image: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1648862909584515073/S3KDvPUY.png'
  },
  expires: '2023-05-21T04:11:33.758Z'
}
=================================================================
```

Second run:

```
Session : {
  user: { name: undefined, email: undefined, image: undefined },
  expires: '2023-05-21T04:18:14.709Z'
}
=================================================================
```

What happened to my session data why it's runs twice and invalidate the data?
Thank you for your explaination

I try to login using twitter, but later the session data are invalid because it's run twice and at the second time the data are missing